# How to filter PivotTable to only show values contained in another column using vba

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a vba macro that will filter a pivot table so that the only values that show are the ones that also exist in a list of items on another worksheet.

The pivot table has the following construction:

```
Raw Material Item Code | other column1 | other column2 | ... etc.
       1001            |               |               |
       1002            |               |               |       
       10PT            |               |               |
         .             |               |               |
         .             |               |               |
         .             |               |               |
```

I am wanting to place a filter on the "Raw Material Item Code" Field.

The other table is simply a list of items, starting at A1 on a separate worksheet that looks like this:

```
    A
1| 1001
2| 1234
3| 8123
4| 1004
5|   .
6|   .
7|   .
8|   .
```

Essentially, I want to be able to add or remove items to the list and have the PivotTable automatically filtered to show only the items where it's "Raw Material Item Code" value matches an item in the other list.

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim NewCat As String
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim Pi As PivotItem

'   This is getting a collection of all of the values containted in the other table.

        Worksheets("test").Select
        Worksheets("test").Range("A1").Select

        Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            NewCat = ActiveCell.Value
                col.Add (NewCat)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop

'   This is interating through the Pivot Items in the Pivot Table and setting their visability to False.

        With Worksheets("Trim Inventory - NC-Obsolete").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Raw Material Item Code")
            For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count - 1
                .PivotItems(.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
            Next i

'   This is interating back through the Pivot Items in the Pivot Table and setting the visability of the items that exist in the 
'   other table to True.

             For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count - 1
                For Each c In col
                    If UCase(.PivotItems(.PivotItems(i).Name).Value) = c Then
                        .PivotItems(.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
                    End If
                Next c
            Next i

        End With

End Sub
```

When this runs, it just filters out everything. Can someone please point me in the correct direction? I am also open for complete code change suggestions seeing as how I understand that this approach may not be the most efficient one.

Comment: Personally I would add a helper column with a countif() formula, then filter the pivot table on that column being greater than zero.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through line-by-line using the debugger?

Comment: I have not, that is a good idea. I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub partNum()
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set pt = Worksheets("Feuil4").PivotTables(1)
pt.PivotCache.op
pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
End Sub
```